# Flexslider inside Flexslider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I'm trying to render various Flexsliders inside another Flexslider in a wordpress page.
This is the jquery so far:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() { 
          $('#vert').flexslider({
             animation: "fade",
             useCSS: true, 
             pauseOnHover: false,
             touch: true, 
             slideshow: false,
             namespace: "gal-",
             selector: '.slides:first > li',
            }); 
      });
})

jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() { 
          $('#defgal').flexslider({
             animation: "fade",
             useCSS: true, 
             pauseOnHover: false,
             touch: true, 
             selector: '.slides:first > li',
            }); 
      });
})
```

Also,the "slide" animation neither the "vertical" direction work, and options for the parent gallery applies to the children ones, such us the "false" slideshow.

Any tips?

It's a local installation, no url available.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling jQuery LOAD inside ready? And why are you calling them 2 times?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770351/woothemes-flexslider-one-unique-flexslider-inside-another-flexslider-is-it-p

Comment: I already checked that post and added the selector option that it fixed some stuff.

Comment: I added the code on that post but still doesnt work

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You have an error on the page Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined :)

Comment: oops i uploaded the local route, now it should work